# log4j with grails: How to get appender file name at run time?

Tags: groovy, log4j, grails

I am working on a grails app where in development mode, I log some calculations to a log file through log4j.

I want to provide a service which will read the log file and make its contents available to a developer so they can see what is being logged in the log file.

Is there a way I can get the log4j appender file name at run time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your logging configuration is set up like:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        file name: 'myFileAppender', file: '/tmp/myFile.log'
    }

    debug 'myFileAppender': 'myFileLogger'
}
```

You can access the `myFileLogger` Logger's file name like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

def appender = (FileAppender)Logger.getLogger('myFileLogger').getAppender('myFileAppender')
def fileName = appender.file
```

Answer (score 3):

This will find the filename of the first appender:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*

Logger.rootLogger.allAppenders.find{it instanceof FileAppender}?.fileName
```